# When I shut down a GCP project, I receive an unknown error with a tracking number

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I create and delete (shut down) GCP projects all the time.

When I try to shut down a project, I receive an unknown error with a tracking number.

Tracking number: 6576339999931916451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons why you are not able to shutdown a project.

1. The most common one, could be that your project has active endpoint services.
   This would list and delete any such remaining service:

`$ gcloud --project=your-project-id endpoints services list
$ gcloud --project=your-project-id endpoints services delete <endpoint-service>`

2. Another reason could be that the project belongs to an organization for which the administrator has restricted project deletion, including to project owners.
   In this case, even if you contacted customer support, is most likely unable to shutdown the project on your behalf.

Comment: In both cases, at least gcloud should give you a more descriptive error instead of just a tracking number. In case 1., the error should be something like there being active children and in case 2. it should say that it's prohibited by an org policy or missing permissions. If this is not working, try updating gcloud. If it still doesn't work, please either reach out to GCP support or file a public issue tracker bug.

Comment: Here are some guidelines about troubleshooting project deletion: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/troubleshooting-project-deletion